# How to typedef the iterator of a nested container?

Tags: c++, iterator, typedef, type-traits

What is the proper way to declare the iterator i in the following code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class Mat> 
void f(const Mat& mat) 
{
    typedef typename Mat::value_type::iterator itr;
    //itr i = (mat.begin())->begin(); //This Line Gives an error
    typeof((mat.begin())->begin()) i = (mat.begin())->begin(); 
}

int main() 
{
    vector<vector<int> > vvi;
    f(vvi);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: not using const is the error. I was not able to understand this from the error line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it the STL way and pass iterators, not containers:

```
//Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
template<typename It> 
void f(It begin, It end) 
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type cont;
    typedef typename cont::const_iterator const_iterator; // note the const_ pfx
    const_iterator i = begin->begin();
    // ...
}

int main() 
{
    vector<vector<int> > vvi;
    f(vvi.begin(), vvi.end());
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Where does cont:: namespace comes from?

Comment: @fabrizioM: `typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type cont;`

Answer (score 2):

Your container is `const`, but your iterator type is not. Make that `const_iterator`:

```
template<class Mat> 
void f(const Mat& mat) 
{
    typedef typename Mat::value_type::const_iterator itr;

    itr i = mat.begin()->begin();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the const iterator:

```
typedef typename Mat::value_type::const_iterator itr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass as a const&, so you [need a const_iterator](http://codepad.org/TpaG3eg7):

```
typedef typename Mat::value_type::const_iterator itr;
itr i = (mat.begin())->begin();
```