# public: typedef other_class::const_iterator my_class::const_iterator - acceptable?

Tags: c++, stl, typedef

I'm looking for a way to use std::set::const_iterator as const_iterator of my own class.

My code (which actually behaves correct and compiles fine), goes like:

```
class MyClass{

public:
    typedef std::set<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;

const_iterator begin() const {
    return mySet->begin();
}

const_iterator end() const {
    return mySet->end();
}

}; // MyClass
```

So, my question is: Is my way of using the const_iterator acceptable and also in the STL intended form?

**Edit**: Related question and answers at [How to typedef the iterator of a nested container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820843/how-to-typedef-the-iterator-of-a-nested-container)

Comment: What is `T`?  I'm guessing that you have templated `MyClass`?, in which case I think you will want a `typedef typename std::set<T>...`?  But otherwise looks good to me...

Comment: Nope, my class is not templated. I was a bit imprecise there. Actually T is of type unsigned int.

Comment: Okay, I think its fine then.  I seem to remeber  Bjarne Stroustrup doing the same thing in his book  `The c++ programming language` (I don't have it to hand to reference it - which is why this is not an answer) but I think you are doing things right.

Comment: Ah... thats cool then :) Do you remember the name of Staustroups book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at other C++ Standard Library container adapters like `std::queue`. `std::queue` is just an adapter on top of an underlying container (by default a `std::deque`).

This is exactly the method used in those adapters. Given that, I would say your implementation is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of having the internal type is so that generic code can use your class without prior knowledge of the implementation. The main point is that there is a `const_iterator`, and that it has the semantics of a constant iterator. The fact that you are borrowing the iterator from the internal type is just an implementation detail that calling code should not care about.

That is, the problem would be not defining the `const_iterator` internal type, as that would increase coupling in user code, where they would have to use `std::set<T>::const_iterator` explicitly, and that in turn makes the type of the member part of the interface (i.e. you can no longer change the implementation of the member without breaking user code).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. You may store a `std::set<T>::const_iterator` anywhere you like, and making an alias of the type is even more okay.

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly encapsulated, but a perfectly valid technique.